# How to electronize an ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor WebAssembly app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, electron, blazor-webassembly, electron.net

I have created a new Blazor WebAssembly project and made it ASP.NET Core hosted (so, Visual Studio created three projects, one for the server, the actual WebAssembly client project, as well as a class library holding types used by both apps). Then, I just followed the documentation at https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET to electronize the server app. In theory, everything should be fine.

Problems occur when I try to run the app via `electronize start`. The build fails with the following error.

```
...Microsoft.NET.ILLink.targets(143,5): error NETSDK1102: Optimizing assemblies for size is not supported for the select
ed publish configuration. Please ensure that you are publishing a self-contained app. ...
Error occurred during dotnet publish: 1
```

Of course, I can imagine what the actual problem is. The Electron build tries to publish the assemblies for the current target platform, which is `x64` in my case, but this is not supported for `blazor-wasm` projects. What I basically want to achieve is that the client build output gets included with the electronized server app.

**Update**

The following command successfully builds the electronized app, if the `PublishSingleFile` and `PublishReadyToRun` properties are set to `false`. Though, this is far from optimal since it creates an app that comes with a performance penalty (increased load time).

```
electronize build /target win /PublishSingleFile false /PublishReadyToRun false
```

Sadly, the switches currently do not work with the `electronize start` command.

Comment: I see that this has been filed as a bug already https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET/issues/532

Comment: You might want to skip to .Net 6 & blazor desktop.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yes, that might the better solution anyway. The reason why I considered Electron.NET is because this app is not intended to be rolled out to the cloud (or another on-prem server), otherwise, I could make it a PWA.